# How to Support Multiple Signed in Users in ASP.NET Core?

Tags: asp.net-core, authentication, azure-ad-msal

I am building a webapp that uses OpenIdConnect to have users sign in, sample can be found [here](https://github.com/Azure-Samples/active-directory-aspnetcore-webapp-openidconnect-v2/tree/master/1-WebApp-OIDC/1-3-AnyOrgOrPersonal). With MSAL.js, specifically the react implementation, a client can tell what accounts are signed in. This allows you to build a switch account menu, as seen below.

```
import { useMsal } from "@azure/msal-react";

const { instance, accounts } = useMsal();
```

[image: accounts menu]

I am trying to recreate the same menu, but using server side authentication instead of client side. I can sign in with the example above, and can keep multiple accounts signed in by using:

```
builder.Services.Configure<OpenIdConnectOptions>(OpenIdConnectDefaults.AuthenticationScheme, options =>
{
    options.Prompt = "select_account";
});
```

However, I want to get a list of signed in users in the controller. `HttpContext.User` only holds one user, and its identity/claims. Does ASP.NET Core expose a way to find out what users are signed in, or would I have to handle that manually?

Comment: no, it's impossible. For example, you are using azure ad as the identity provider so that users can use their microsoft account to sign in. then only azure ad can know `what users are signed in` and for your app, it only set up a session with azure ad and then your app can know the user information in this session. for each stand-alone session it only knows user in it and can't know users in other sessions.

Comment: what you can try is that after each user signed in, save the user into the database and when you want to get all the users who are signed in, scanning the table.

Comment: @TinyWang Makes sense, Is that how the MSAL.js is working?

Comment: MSAL microsoft authentication library maybe ... so it used Azure  AD